# Change path to project Microsoft Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I am working on a website on visual studio, I am a little new to visual studio and I am trying to move my whole directory for my website to my google drive so I can work on it on multiple computers.

How would I go about changing the source files located in the project file for visual studios.

Or is there an easier way?

Comment: Tried copying everything including the solution folder?

Comment: An alternative you may consider is simply adding your solution's source files to a cloud version control system - e.g. GitHub or BitBucket. But in general, VS projects will store relative paths, so as long as you keep the folder structure across the solution, and the solution sln file at the root, it should load from any root folder.

Comment: Yah I have everything copied into google drive, the problem is the visual studio project file won't recognize the new path. How do I go about changing the path for the sln file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easiest way is to Remove the project in Visual Studio and then Add Existing Project and point to your new location.

[image]
[image]

You could alternatively use a text editor to edit the `.sln` file.  The top of the file defines `Project` elements:

```
 Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = 
       "SignalR.Backplane", "SignalR.Backplane\SignalR.Backplane.csproj", 
       "{EBF95949-81E0-4571-8014-E91B7577FB07}"
 EndProject
```

The second property is the path (relative or absolute) to the csproj file representing the project.